# Xamarin Forms - How to get the json string in POST method response?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, post

I created a listview where it displays all categories based on the data from an API "cat_code", and if you tapped any of the it will transfer the value of the "cat_code" into a variable "selectedItem"

**MenuCategories.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="MyCategory" ItemSelected="MyCategory_ItemSelected" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"   >
                    <Label Font="30" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" x:Name="categoryname" Text="{Binding cat_code}" 
                       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**MenuCategories.xaml.cs**

```
private string selectedItem;

public MenuCategories()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetCategoryAsync();
}

public async Task GetCategoryAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://ropenrom24-001-site1.etempurl.com/potangina/final/Restserver/index.php/category/view");
    var cat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Catergory>>(response);
    MyCategory.ItemsSource = cat;
}

private void MyCategory_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedCategory = e.SelectedItem as Catergory;
    if (selectedCategory != null)
        selectedItem = selectedCategory.cat_code;
    DisplayAlert("Test", "Selected: " + selectedItem, "OK");

    Catergory cat = new Catergory();
    {
        cat.cat_code = selectedItem;
    }

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cat);

    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var result = await client.PostAsync("http://ropenrom24-001-site1.etempurl.com/potangina/final/Restserver/index.php/Products/view_cat", content);
}
```

If I post a cat_code:Asian it will display all of cat_code that has `cat_code:Asian` what I want to happen is how to get the underlined in this picture? 
[image: picture]

and transfer it to a viewmodel where i can display it to this listview?

**MenuView.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="ViewMenu">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding menu_image ,StringFormat='https://i.imgur.com/{0:F0}.png'}" Scale="1" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding menu_name}" Font="30"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding menu_price,StringFormat=''}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding menu_availability} "/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Menus.cs**

```
public class Menus
{
    public string menu_code { get; set; }
    public string cat_code { get; set; }
    public string menu_name { get; set; }
    public string menu_price { get; set; }
    public string menu_description { get; set; }
    public string menu_image { get; set; }
    public string menu_inventory { get; set; }
    public string menu_availability { get; set; }
}
```

Basically my question is how to get the json string underlined in the picture above?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/69ZPH.png i'm sorry

Comment: it's all working fine

Comment: you can try it in postman
http://ropenrom24-001-site1.etempurl.com/potangina/final/Restserver/index.php/products/view_cat


Post this
{"cat_code":"Asian"}

Comment: The function `GetStringAsync` does a `GET` request, not a `POST`, if the server requires a `POST`, then use `PostAsync`

Comment: @Barnstokkr the post request is not yet included in the code

Comment: @Barnstokkr i edited it you sorry idid'nt notice that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this.

```
string json_response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

the json_response should contain the data you need.